# Linear system of a relative effective divisor on an arithmetic surface contains vertical divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, divisors, line-bundles

I am puzzled by the behavior of some divisors in my attempt to understand the relative Picard functor $\mathrm{Pic}_{X/S}$ of an arithmetic surface $\pi:X\to S$. This is defined by *relative divisors* $D$, which means that they are flat over $S$. However not all divisors in the linear system $|D|$ are flat over $S$.

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}$, and $p$ a prime.
Consider the arithmetic surface $X = \mathrm{Proj}R[x_0,x_1,x_2]/(x_0x_1-px_2^2)$.
This is a regular quadric hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^2_R$, which can also be seen as the blowup of $\mathbb{P}^1_R$ at a closed point over $p$.

The fibers of the map $\pi:X \to S = \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ are given by
$$X_q \cong \begin{cases}
    \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_q} & q \neq p\\
    \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_q} \cup_0 \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_q} & q = p\\
    \end{cases}
$$
so the sole reducible fiber is the union of two projective lines over $p$, which intersect in the unique singular point of $\pi$.

Let $\mathcal{L} = i^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1)$ be the pullback of the hyperplane bundle. $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{L}) = \langle{x_0,x_1,x_2\rangle}$ is a rank 3 $R$-module.

Since each hyperplane intersects the generic fiber in two points, one would expect that each section of $\mathcal{L}$ defines two points over $R$ (i.e. a flat, degree 2 morphism to $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$. This is generically the case, but some of the members of the linear system $|\mathcal{L}|$ also contain vertical components, which are not flat.

Namely, the loci of $x_0,x_1$ are isomorphic to $R[t]/(pt^2)$, which contain a $(R/p)[t]$ in addition to the expected $R[t]/(t^2)$. Over the generic fiber these define tangent hyperplanes.

**Question**: What gives? Can I not parametrize relative effective divisors using a linear system? How should I remedy this? Is this still the best way to describe the relative Picard functor $\mathrm{Pic}_{X/S}$? I know the singularity is contributing to issue.

Maybe a better question would be:

If $\tilde{X} \xrightarrow{\beta} X$ is the blowup at a closed point, then $\beta$ increases the Picard rank by 1.
But what is the relation between the relative Picard functors $\mathrm{Pic}_{\tilde{X}/S}, \mathrm{Pic}_{X/S}$?

Comment: I can highly recommend reading the book "Neron models" by Bosch, Lutkebohmert, and Raynaud. It really has a *very* good discussion of the Picard functor and the Jacobians of relative curves. In fact, some mathematician I know thinks this is the best book every written.

Comment: @Johan thanks, yes, I have been consulting several references and this book most of all. One problem is that each reference seems to have at least one hypothesis differing from the objects I'm looking at, and this question stems from my difficulty resolving the differences on my own.
In particular, BLR often prefers to use rigidificators of degree 1, whereas I am particularly interested in rigidificators of degree 2 (which are behind the scenes in this question).

Comment: I agree that it is a fantastic book, one that impresses me more every time I read through it. Sadly it's taking me longer to digest than I would like.

Comment: The Picard functor isn't always separated. So what can happen is that the maximal separated quotient (which you get by dividing by the closure of the zero section) in the nonseparated guy gives the separated guy (in your special case). This is discussed in BLR (their example of a non-efficective descent is related to this as well IIRC). Just keep at it. Best, Johan

Comment: The issue mentioned by @Johan is discussed in detail in Raynaud's early paper, "Specialization du foncteur de Picard."  Sometimes it really is best to read the primary literature.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks. I've also been trudging through that paper, though it's harder in the French.
One specific issue: it seems he does everything over a valuation ring. Do you know what difficulties there are in extending all of those results to $\mathbb{Z}$ or other Dedekind rings?